# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.bytecode.instrumentation.internal.FieldInterceptionHelper

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, wildfly, classnotfoundexception

During  the validation of entity (before insertion) on my Spring MVC app I get the following error :

```
    ...
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/bytecode/instrumentation/internal/FieldInterceptionHelper
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.PersistenceUtilHelper.isLoadedWithoutReference(PersistenceUtilHelper.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider$1.isLoadedWithoutReference(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:171)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1522)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1507)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:584)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:454)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:406)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:204)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:866)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.bytecode.instrumentation.internal.FieldInterceptionHelper from [Module "deployment.Employee_Ex.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 59 more
```

there is the dependencies in my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fussa</groupId>
    <artifactId>EX</artifactId>
    <name>EX</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <warName>Employee_Ex</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>



</project>
```

The above issue only exist during the validation  of fields.
How can i resolve this issue ?
thanks for any suggestions..

Comment: What application server are you using?

Comment: Im using wildfly 10..

Comment: You will need to create a jboss-deployment-structure.xml in your WAR to provide it the spring modules it needs at runtime.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error mentioned is occurring due to a possible clash of dependency versions.

WildFly already provides both *hibernate-core* and *hibernate-validator* dependencies in *<wildfly_dir>\modules\system\layers\base\org\hibernate*.

In the case of WildFly10, the dependencies' versions are the following:

- hibernate-core-5.0.7.Final
- hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final

Therefore, on your *pom.xml*, you could place your Hibernate dependencies as provided and let the container use its own:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But if you want to provide your own dependencies, as mentioned on [WildFly 10 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly), you should provide a *jboss-deployment-structure.xml*, where you basically tell WildFly to disregard it's own dependencies:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This way, the container will load the dependencies that were packaged with your application and that are present on your WAR's *WEB-INF/lib* folder.

**EDIT**

After going to the [source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-entitymanager/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpa/internal/util/PersistenceUtilHelper.java) of `PersistenceUtilHelper.isLoadedWithoutReference`, one notices that, in Hibernate 5.1, it no longer references the class `FieldInterceptionHelper`, on line 119, where the error occurs. Whereas in the version 5.0 it [still does](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.0.CR3/org/hibernate/jpa/internal/util/PersistenceUtilHelper.java).

I also suggest you to add the most recent version of the *hibernate-entitymanager* dependency, in order to be in accordance with the other Hibernate dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i added the jboss-deployment-structure.xml to my src/webapp/WEB-INF folder .. and put ur code on it..still got the same error ! :)

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final
hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final
hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final
```